# How can I add a menu at the start of a code to choose which part of code the use wants to use in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 codes. I want to put both of them together into one code where I can then choose which code I want to use. For example, when you run the code: "Press 1 if you wish to find the volume that the bore will produce, press 2 if you wish to find the volume by giving length and radius: " Something like that.

```
import math
pi = math.pi
a = float(input("What is the minimum volume that is required? (cubic meters): "))
b = float(input("How long do you need the tunnel to be? (metres): "))
r2 = a/(pi)/b
r = math.sqrt(r2)
rrounded = (round(r*4)/(4))
if rrounded < r:
    new_radius = (rrounded+0.25)
    print("Bore radius size required: " + str(new_radius))
else:
    new_radius=rrounded
    print(str(new_radius))
total_volume = ((pi)*(new_radius**2)*(b))
total_volume1 = str(round(total_volume, 2))
print("Exact volume produced (with bore-size above and the tunnel length specified): " +
(str(total_volume1)))
```

```
import math
pi = math.pi
h = float(input('How long does the tunnel need to be?(meters) '))
r = float(input('What is the radius of the tunnel? '))
volume = pi*r**2*h
volume_ = str(round(volume, 2))
print(volume_)
```

I apologise for my terrible attempts at trying to make indents, I still haven't quite figured out how to ask questions on here properly. As I said before, I want to use a code that gives the user the option to choose what they want to do when the code runs. Thanks!

Comment: Define each different section of code as a function. Use an `input()` combined with an if/else to determine which to call based on user input. If you want a graphical menu, you'll need something like Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Define the functions you want in the menu and do something like this

```
def menu():
    print('The options are bellow:\n\
                1. ..\n\
                2. ..\n\n')
    menu = input('Choose the option:\n')
    if menu == '1':
        return function1()
    if menu == '2':
        return function2()
    else:
        print('error')
        return menu()
```